# deploy corda nodes on kubernetes containers

Tags: deployment, corda

I have a corda example and spring web server built and deployed in azure vm.

Now I would like to try run each node in kubernetes containers. Any references?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so this is totally doable. Take a look at this example repo I found online on running corda docker containers in a docker compose cluster along with the individual processes.

Hope this helps:

https://github.com/EricMcEvoyR3/corda-docker-compose